# ZendFramework and open ID login, Is the ZF up to date?

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

I am trying to integrate an openID login in a ZF project (using the MVC). I get failures.
When I traced the code I see the failures originate from:
OpenId/Consumer.php (line ~740). Those lines try to analyze the open id protocol version
from the first request done to the open id provider.
The regexp in the ZF expect to receive HTML with a LINK tag:

```
/<link[^>]*href=(["\
```

While when I look on the response, from google for example,
I see I get XML.
Google url I use:
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

The result I get from there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
  <XRD>
  <Service priority="0">
  <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
  <Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>

  <URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud</URI>
  </Service>
  </XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

Am I using the wrong link to google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a patch for ZF that does most of the trick http://ak33m.com/?p=71

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code in the [ZF trunk](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/OpenId/Consumer.php), it seems that currently, XRDS based discovery is not supported:

```
/* TODO: OpenID 2.0 (7.3) XRI and Yadis discovery */
```

ZF currently supports the HTML based one and Google returns an XDRS document with the endpoint address on it with their OpenId entry URL.

Comment: Thanks. For my very first OpenID attempt I used to Google URL thinking it would work out of the box. I can stop hitting my head now.